# How do teens in Northern England greet each other?

Tags: single-word-requests, speech

Do they say "hi" or "hey" or "hello", or what do they say when they meet someone they know on the street?

Comment: They say all of those things, and lots of other things too. Do you really think an exhaustive answer is possible?

Comment: Possibly "Ey up, pet, hawaay the lads". Or possibly not.

Comment: In Wigan, according to my wife, they say "all reet?"

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelHarvey Where I live, kids say "hi" often, "hello" rarely, and "hey" never. Apparently there is a convention at work. I would think that similar conventions exist among the youth elsewhere.

Comment: It is absurd to seek, or make, generalisations. Where I live teens say "Hi", "Hey", "Alright?", "Yo!", "hallo", "hello", "hullo", "homeboy!", "salut!", "wotcher"... I could continue this list indefinitely. My son aged 17 says "me daaaater" in a fake Jamaican accent to his best pal, who replies, likewise, "cha man!".

Comment: What was a cool greeting at one time is now dismally 'lame' and behind the times, e.g. "wassup".